# Adding Gradle Dependency Breaks Gradle Build

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I added the stripe sdk to my kotlin app and can no longer build my application.
Addition to grade file:

```
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:16.8.2'
```

Build error:

```
     /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6fabb8e15860d0b2ea75a56e95ee9aa5/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.
```

Removing the stripe dependency fixes the issue. I also tried deleting the cache folder referenced in the error message and it was just recreated and the issue persisted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a mismatch between the kotlin library used in your project and the version of the plugin that is not compatible.

Upgrade your Gradle version by going to File>Project Structure.
Ps:(also try downgrading your kotlin version to one of the 1.4.x versions)

Answer (score 0):

[Another developer ran into this same issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/3718) and solved it by upgrading Gradle

> I updated my gradle like this
>
> ```
> // id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions' deprecated
> id 'kotlin-parcelize'
> ```
>
> and in project gradle add this
> `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"`
>
> so now it works.